# Platform Command Framework vs Platform UI Command Design

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on Eclipse plugin development.

Can anyone point out the difference between

[**Platform Command Framework**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework) and 
[**Platform UI Command Design**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_UI_Command_Design)

I am forced to know about them, but as a beginner am unable to differentiate them both. I hope this is a valid question to be asked here. The links provided are too advanced for me.

Answer (score 1):

The first article is basically an input for the second one. It explains common architecture of Command Framework and how to use it. The second article specifically describes how to create UI elements, like menus and toolbars and contribute them into your application, using various approaches (actions framework, command framework).

Shortly speaking: commands allow to have more dynamic approach of creating UI elements. For instance, one plugin may contribute toolbar item with a command, and other plugins may specify handlers for this command as they wish. If you create a toolabr item and use an action, you are bound to a class, which handles this action.